# Date conversion in UTC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working ruby on rails. In that I have a doubt in date conversion from current timezone to UTC.

The date conversion function is

```
function date_conversion(date){
    out = moment(date, "DD/MM/YYYY").format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    var utc_time = moment.tz(out, zone).tz('UTC').format();
    return utc_time;
}
```

Here params date let as "12/10/2019" which is in string format and let the zone is ""Asia/Kolkata".

After executing the date_conversion function the values are

```
   out = moment(date, "DD/MM/YYYY").format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

The output of out = "2019-10-12"

```
   var utc_time = moment.tz(out, zone).format();
```

The value of utc_time is 2019-10-12T00:00:00+05:30. There is no problem while using above. But when  i am trying to convert to UTC as below

```
    var utc_time = moment.tz(out, zone).tz("UTC").format();
```

I got 2019-10-11T18:30:00Z.  In this situation I need of date in UTC but that date not to be changed. Please tell anybody some idea for this

```
$('#filter_id_linguist').on("click",function (event) {
 if($("#available_for_id").val()){
 var date = $("#available_for_id").val();
 $("#filter_forms_linguist_available_for").val(time_conversion(date));
 }
 else
 {
 $("#filter_forms_linguist_available_for").val("");
 }
});
```

On above Javascript i am using function time_conversion. The id which are used in JS are comes from below rails form fields.

```
.form-group
= f.label :with_bookings_from_date, "With bookings from", class: 'sr-only'
.input-group.date{ style: "width:180px;", data: { behaviour: 'linguist-datepicker' } }
  // For time zone conversion
  = f.hidden_field :with_bookings_from_date
  = text_field_tag :with_bookings_from_date_display, '', value: @linguist_filter_form.with_bookings_from_date, placeholder: 'With bookings from', class: 'form-control', id: "with_bookings_from_date_id"
  %span.input-group-addon
    %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-calendar


= f.submit 'Filter', class: 'btn btn-default', id: "filter_id_linguist"
```

I need help on how to convert date into UTC?

Comment: That's Javascript, no? Where's the Ruby/Rails integration? Where do you need help?

Comment: @SebastianPalma sorry I edited this question. In that I added the  Ruby/Rails integration. I need help on converting date around the  different zones to UTC.

Comment: You have omitted the `var` keyword and semicolons on the second line `var out = moment(date, "DD/MM/YYYY").format('YYYY-MM-DD');`. That makes `out` an implicit global. I would really recommend writing javascript in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) which helps you catch sloppy errors.

Comment: Personally, I like to always have UTC datetimes and use rails' and javascript's I18n localization features so I don't have to mess with timezones myself. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#internationalization-and-localization and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat

Comment: Naming a variable and handling timezone are the most difficult part of programming. Any way `2019-10-12T00:00:00+05:30` and `2019-10-11T18:30:00Z` represents same time. Think about your friend is in `UTC` timezone and you are in `Asia/Kolkata`. When you call your friend and ask the time/date he will say it's `2019-10-11` here and time is `18:30`. At the same time if you look at the calendar/clock, you will see `2019-10-12` and 12 am!!! Now describe what is you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

When you do `moment('2019-10-12', 'Asia/Kolkata')`, you're telling momentjs to create a moment instance for `2019-10-12` as if you're in `Asia/Kolkata` timezone. Which is `2019-10-12T00:00:00+05:30`, however this is not in UTC. the `+05:30` is just to denote that the timezone is `Asia\Kolkata` and **doesn't mean** that the actual datetime is `2019-10-12 00:05:30`

> Times are expressed in local time, together with a time zone offset in hours and minutes. A time zone offset of "+hh:mm" indicates that the date/time uses a local time zone which is "hh" hours and "mm" minutes ahead of UTC. A time zone offset of "-hh:mm" indicates that the date/time uses a local time zone which is "hh" hours and "mm" minutes behind UTC.

From https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

Hence, when you format it back to UTC, you would get UTC time which is behind 5:30hrs

I would recommend not to handle timezone conversions on the client side considering variable client time zones. If possible, you should perform these timezone related conversions on the server side where you would be definite of the default timezone(depends on the server timezone)

More details here: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/its-about-time-zones